# Comparing characters(factors) in multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a data frame that contains proteins with different localisation annotations from multiple databases. I would like to compare those entries for each protein (row) and write the result into a new col with the original entry if they agree and "disagreement" if an entry differs in the cols.

I suppose the answer has an easy solution but I didn't find it yet, any help is much appreciated!
If possible I would appreciate a tidyverse solution :)

Thanks!

Sebastian

```
start_df <- data.frame(protein = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
             location_1 = c("membrane", "membrane", "nucleus", "mito"),
             location_2 = c("membrane", "nucleus", "nucleus", "membrane"),
             location_3 = c("membrane", "membrane", "nucleus", "membrane"),
             location_4 = c("membrane", "membrane", "nucleus", "mito"))

expectation <- data.frame(protein = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
             location_1 = c("membrane", "membrane", "nucleus", "mito"),
             location_2 = c("membrane", "nucleus", "nucleus", "membrane"),
             location_3 = c("membrane", "membrane", "nucleus", "membrane"),
             location_4 = c("membrane", "membrane", "nucleus", "mito"),
             location_all = c("membrane", "disagrement", "nucleus", "disagrement"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

start_df <- data.table::data.table(protein = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
             location_1 = c("membrane", "membrane", "nucleus", "mito"),
             location_2 = c("membrane", "nucleus", "nucleus", "membrane"),
             location_3 = c("membrane", "membrane", "nucleus", "membrane"),
             location_4 = c("membrane", "membrane", "nucleus", "mito"))

df <- data.table::as.data.table(t(x = start_df)) # transpose the dataframe for comparison in the apply statement
colnames(df) <- as.character(df[1,])
df1 <- df[-1,] # take the colnames out for the comparison between the cellular compartments you want to compare
ls <- apply(X = df1,MARGIN = 2, FUN = unique) # take unique - so that you have only one element if they all "agree" and only one location is there
start_df$unique <- ls # add this to your initial dataframe
res <- start_df %>% mutate(location_all =if_else( condition = grepl(",",start_df$unique), true = "disagrement", false = location_1 )) # write a new column with your desired outcome
```

you might run into problems if the strings are slightly different for example: "membrane" and "Membrane" etc..

hope it helps & best wishes

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I made sure all location annotations are the same before this step :)